# Show a single DIV from remote site to new site. Only http access to remote host

Tags: web-development, proxy

we have cisco CWS working which has a web administration site. On that site it has DIV with 'overall summary'.

We would like to show that DIV on a centralized monitoring system web that we are doing for ourselves.

Is it possible to do a proxypass from apache to only that DIV?
How I should manage the autentication process before reaching that DIV?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to grab a specific id or class on a remote page and display it on another.

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) is a tool for testing websites and web applications. You can probably use it to log into the site however it does the authentication and then get the contents of that DIV and save it to a file. Then you can include that file using an IFRAME on your centralized monitoring system.

Comment: That's overly complex for something like this

Comment: I don't think so. No more complex then writing your own solution from scratch especially since it requires authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably best off writing a script in ruby or PHP that scrapes the contents of that div every *n* minutes and saves it to a file. Then you can iframe it in your monitoring system.